# How to call a public method that is defined like this: this.name = function(){return 2;}

Tags: function, javascript

```
   var CoreGroups = new function(){
      this.name = function(){return 'name test'};

      var functionName = function(){
         // here I want to call the name() function
         a = this.name(); // doesnt work: this.name is not a function
         b = name(); // doesn't work too: name is not defined

      }
   }
```

Any idea on how to call the name() function from the functionName() function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
var CoreGroups = new function(){
    var self = this;

    this.name = function(){return 'name test'};

    var functionName = function() {
        var a = self.name();
    };
}
```

Comment: That's not good. Image I have a Class named Thumb, and I have 100 thumbs, how I will set the self then? it's not the case of the example in my question.

Comment: Each instance of the class will have a separate `self` variable.  (This code goes inside the function, as in my edit)